# Are there any "two-sided" strong blenders?

Tags: cr.crypto-security, randomness, extractors

My question is related to [explicit extractors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_extractor#Explicit_extractors) and [strong blenders](http://books.google.com/books?id=1C83C5rMQKIC&pg=PA337&lpg=PA337&dq=entropy%20%22strong%20blender%22&source=bl&ots=I8QX9XhoMy&sig=6mJkBcNXf2KPDK7haVPjOsNMiUs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=v2ObT8rZIumSiQLQx-1-&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=entropy%20%22strong%20blender%22&f=false%29). We can define *explicit strong blender* in a straight forward way.

I want to know if there are any known *explicit strong blenders* $\small\text{BLE}$ such
that

$$\: (X,Y) \mapsto \small\text{BLE}\normalsize(Y,X) \:$$

is also a strong blender?

Comment: Hi -- is there another page that defines blenders? Googling "blenders and extractors" yields interesting, but ultimately irrelevant results.

Comment: blender = "deterministic two-source extractor" $\:$ see http://books.google.com/books?id=3VMrmyr19vEC&pg=PA334&lpg=PA334&dq=randomness+extraction+blender&source=bl&ots=TJT5l7b45M&sig=8VJN3sGqdh2tooaoa3bgnzRIBTY&hl=en